# building a matrix through use of constructor

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var Evalcard =  function(number) {
    if (number == 1) {
        this.name = "Ace";
        this.value = 11;
    }
    else if (number == 11) {
        this.name = "Jack";
        this.value = 10;
    }
    else if (number == 12) {
        this.name = "Queen";
        this.value = 10;
    }
    else if (number == 13) {
        this.name = "King";
        this.value = 10;
    }

    return [this.name,this.value];
}

var Buildmatrix = function(mat,suit) {
    row = [];
    var cardeval = new Evalcard(r);
    for (r = 1;r <= 13;r++) {
        cardeval(r);
        row[r] = [r,cardeval(r)[0],suit,cardeval(r)[1]]
        mat.push(row);
    }

    return row;
}
```

Is my use of the constructor here correct? can I call an instance of `Evalcard()` by placing the arguments next to the new object (in this case `var cardeval`)?

Comment: You need to choose a different name for eval, is a javascript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Evalcard()" constructor returns an array.  You cannot make a function call to an array; it doesn't make sense.

I think what you want is just:

```
function Buildmatrix(mat,suit) {
    var row = [];
    for (var r = 1;r <= 13;r++) {
        var nameval = new Evalcard(r); // thanks @patrick dw
        row[r] = [r,nameval[0],suit,nameval[1]]
        mat.push(row);
    }

    return row;
}
```

(Note also that I added back some missing `var` keywords — don't forget `var`!)

<strike>Since you're returning an array anyway, there's no reason to treat it as a constructor.</strike>

Comment: @Pointy--Could you explain what part of my code did not make sense? The code your have posted looks more or less the same with the exception of calling `Evalcard()` inside the loop...

Comment: @Pointy: *"there's no reason to treat it as a constructor"* Except that he's using `this` in the `Evalcard` function, so if you call it without `new`, you'll pollute the global.

Comment: @codeninja: Your function is returning an Array, but you're treating it as though it's a function when you do `cardeval(r)`. It's like creating an Array `var arr = [1,2,3];` and then trying to invoke it like a function `arr()`. It just won't work because an only a function can be invoked.

Comment: @patrick dw - thanks - I think I had imagined I'd rewritten the function too, which would probably be a good idea ...